# How do I start a Terraria server on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: terraria, linux, hosting, server-administration

I installed Mono on my Ubuntu 12.04 server with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-libtiff-compat main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Here is my installation log:

http://pastebin.com/VNVkpfja

I then used the simple command line of:

```
mono TerrariaServer.exe
```

And this is my server log:

```
$ mono TerrariaServer.exe
Terraria Server v1.3.1.1

n               New World
d <number>      Delete World

Choose World: n
Terraria Server v1.3.1.1

1       Small
2       Medium
3       Large

Choose size: 3
Terraria Server v1.3.1.1

1       Normal
2       Expert

Choose difficulty: 1
Terraria Server v1.3.1.1

Enter world name: World9
Server crash: 7/5/2016 8:52:16 PM
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.JavaScriptUtils' tion. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Collections.HashPrimeNumbers' from assemblersion=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
  at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T].Add (System.Collections.Generic.T item) <0x40bb2ca0 + 0x0007f unknown>:0
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateUnionIterator>c__Iterator1C`1[TSource].MoveNext () <0x40bb1ee0 + 0x001ce unknown>:0
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.JavaScriptUtils..cctor () <0x40bb11f0 + 0x0027c> in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.UpdateCharEscapeFlags () <0x40bb10e0 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>:
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter..ctor (System.IO.TextWriter textWriter) <0x40a375f0 + 0x0007f> in <fil:0
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal (System.Object value, System.Type type, Newtonsofializer jsonSerializer) <0x40a373e0 + 0x000c7> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject (System.Object value, System.Type type, Formatting formatft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) <0x40ae0e40 + 0x0004b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject (System.Object value, Formatting formatting, Newtonsoft.JizerSettings settings) <0x40ae0e00 + 0x00023> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject (System.Object value, Formatting formatting) <0x40ae0d40 <filename unknown>:0
  at Terraria.IO.FavoritesFile.Save () <0x40ae0cd0 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Terraria.IO.FavoritesFile.SaveFavorite (Terraria.IO.FileData fileData) <0x40b70200 + 0x000f3> in <fil:0
  at Terraria.IO.FileData.SetFavorite (Boolean favorite, Boolean saveChanges) <0x40b70190 + 0x0004f> in <fn>:0
  at Terraria.IO.WorldFile.CreateMetadata (System.String name, Boolean cloudSave, Boolean isExpertMode) <00014f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Terraria.Main.DedServ () <0x40960520 + 0x00ca3> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Terraria.Program.LaunchGame (System.String[] args) <0x4091f470 + 0x00167> in <filename unknown>:0

Please send crashlog.txt to support@terraria.org
```

I used to host a 1.1 server via Mono and it would crash occasionally. Any help with this would be well appreciated.

Comment: Based on the error message, it seems you're lacking System.Collections.HashPrimeNumbers. The only site that I could find that references that package is [here](http://vnuget.org/packages/NUnit/3.4.1/files/7/type/System.Collections.HashPrimeNumbers)... I'm not sure if installing that would fix the problem. Have you tried emailing `support@terraria.org` as the trace mentioned?